# convert array object to another

Tags: javascript

I want to convert this:

```
[
    {
        "company": "test"
    },
    {
        "block": "test"
    },
    {
        "start_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    },
    {
        "end_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    },
    {
        "company": "test1"
    },
    {
        "block": "test1"
    },
    {
        "start_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    },
    {
        "end_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    }
]
```

to this:

```
[
    {
        "company": "test",
        "block": "test",
        "start_date": "15/08/2023 15:00",
        "end_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    },
    {
        "company": "test1",
        "block": "test1",
        "start_date": "15/08/2023 15:00",
        "end_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    }
]
```

How to convert like that?

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question body? How can you guarantee that the dates are meant for the company/block properties above them?

Comment: I would fix the API/app/code that's giving that output rather than trying to deal with it after the fact.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get the first key in the array and iterate the array with creation new result objects when this key is encountered:

```js
const [startKey] = Object.keys(arr[0]);

const result = [];
let obj;

for(const item of arr){
  const [[key, val]] = Object.entries(item);
  key === startKey ? result.push(obj = {[key]: val}) : obj[key] = val;
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [
    {
        "company": "test"
    },
    {
        "block": "test"
    },
    {
        "start_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    },
    {
        "end_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    },
    {
        "company": "test1"
    },
    {
        "block": "test1"
    },
    {
        "start_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    },
    {
        "end_date": "15/08/2023 15:00"
    }
] 
</script>
```